# How to print digits with thousand separator?

Tags: sed, format

I'm trying to convert any number from just digits to a new form, where every three digits are separated by a dot starting from the end of the number.

This way, this file:

```
1000
10000
100000
1000000
```

Should become:

```
1.000
10.000
100.000
1.000.000
```

I'm trying to find one sed-command that converts all of these numbers to that form.

I know `sed 's/.\{3\}/&,/g'` does the something similar, but this starts from the beginning of the number instead of the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rev` to reverse each line:

```
$ rev input | sed 's/.../&./g;s/\.$//' | rev
1.000
10.000
100.000
1.000.000
```

`s/\.$//` will remove the otherwise leading period on `100000`:

```
100000 -> 000001 -> 000.001. -> 000.001 -> 100.000
```

Comment: Thank you for the rev tip, this is exactly where i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use GNU `awk`'s `'` modifier to have thousands separator!!

```
$ awk '{printf "%'\''d\n", $0}' file
100
1.000
10.000
100.000
1.000.000.000
```

Or, using Ed Morton's wisdom:

```
awk '{printf "%\047d\n", $0}' file
```

> if you use `\047` instead of `'\''` to represent ' then it'll work in any context in any OS and whether the script is called from the command line or stored in a file and invoked as `awk -f script`.

For a given file

```
$ cat file
100
1000
10000
100000
1000000000
```

From GNU awk user's guide in [Format Modifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html):

> **'**
>
> A single quote or apostrophe character is a POSIX extension to ISO C. It indicates that the integer part of a floating-point value, or the entire part of an integer decimal value, should have a thousands-separator character in it. This only works in locales that support such characters.

Comment: right, and as always if you use `\047` instead of `'\''` to represent `'` then it'll work in any context in any OS and whether the script is called from the command line or stored in a file and invoked as `awk -f script`.

Comment: I actually needed it in sed, but thanks for the elegant solution. The problem is that can't use GNU awk, because it has to work on systems without GNU awk.